# transfer ether of a contract gives execution error

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I have two contracts. When I run a function in contract CourierService that transfers the balance of a deployed contract POD to an ethereum address named arbitrator. It does not work. I get an error. What are the possible reasons for it to fail? The POD contract named mainContract has 12 ether when I run the transferEther function from CourierService

```
contract POD{
address public seller;
address public buyer;
address public nextCourier;
```

..
}

```
contract CourierService{
address public mainContract;//the first original contract
address public parentContract;

 function transferEther(contractState st) OnlyDestinationAddress{
    require(st == contractState.Dispute);//require the child's state is Dispute
    arbitrator.transfer(this.balance);
   if(parentContract == mainContract)
   {
       pod = POD(mainContract);
       pod.setState(POD.contractState.DisputeVerificationFailure);
       arbitrator.transfer(mainContract.balance);//ERROR

   }else{
       .....

   }
}
```

}

Comment: You'll certainly need to share your code for someone to help. You typically don't need to use `this` at all to call a function within the same contract. (It can be used to force "external" calling conventions, but that's an extreme exception.)

Comment: @smarx I am using this to get the balance

Comment: @HayaRaed Are you using contract A to call a function in contract B?

Comment: `this.balance` gives you the amount of ether in the current contract. In other words, `this.balance` is the balance of whatever contract `transferEther` is in. You haven't shared the full code, so I have no idea what `mainContract` is (perhaps the same contract?). This isn't enough information to tell you what is happening.

Comment: @viz I call a function from another contract after creating the instance pod , which is after calling 'this'

Comment: @smarx that is what I thought too, but that is not what am getting in my case .. mainContract is another contract of type POD , when calling this.balance it actually transfers the balance of mainContract, so later when I want to transfer mainContract's balance, i get an exception. The current contract is of type courierService. The code is tooo long to share fully

Comment: @HayaRaed It would be better if you can share the minimum compilable example code, so that we can see the structure.

Comment: "when calling this.balance it actually transfers the balance of mainContract" No, it doesn't. Not unless the current contract is also `mainContract`. You'll either need to figure out your bug by yourself or share more code. (As @viz says, _any_ code that exhibits the problem will work, so try to reproduce it in a small example.)

Comment: @smarx 'this' returned the ether of the current contract when I did some more debugging. So I edited the question, as the error appears when I try to transfer the ether from the POD contract named mainContract

Answer (score 1):

A contract can't forcibly transfer ether from another contract. `recipient.transfer(amount)` transfers `amount` of ether from the contract to the `recipient`.

So what's happening is that this line:

```
arbitrator.transfer(this.balance);
```

is sending all the ether owned by the contract to `arbitrator`. Then this line:

```
arbitrator.transfer(mainContract.balance);
```

tries to transfer *more* ether. Specifically, it tries to transfer the amount of ether held by `mainContract`. If that's more than 0, the call will fail because the contract has an insufficient balance.

If you want `mainContract` to send ether, you'll have to write code in `mainContract` to do that, something like:

```
function transferBalanceTo(address recipient) public {
    require(msg.sender == whoeverIsAllowedToDoThis); // be sure to do some auth

    recipient.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```

Then you can call it from the other contract:

```
mainContract.transferBalanceTo(arbitrator);
```

Comment: Can i do a modifier to allow calls from the courierService contract only? or modifiers can only be used with ethereum addresses of entities not contracts?

Comment: Modifiers can do anything any other code can do.